# elevation leaves shadow on kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, elevation

to highlight the cards on kivymd I put elevation: 3, but when I change the screen in the bottom navigation and go back to the screen with the cards, the shadow that creates the elevation gets stuck and everything becomes black I don't know what the problem is please help

Answer (score 0):

Install kivymd 1.2.0, this worked for me. https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1439#issuecomment-1365039955